# How to get a RegionManager in a boot strapper in Prism

Tags: prism, bootstrapper

I am facing an issue while using method

```
this.regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TextRegion", typeof(TextView));
```

If i write the above code in boot strapper in some method. It does not work because i am not able to get the object of regionmanager from code

```
IRegionManager manager = this.Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
```

Above code throws an exception "Exception message is: The current build operation (build key Build Key[Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Regions.IRegionManager, null]) failed: The current type, Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Regions.IRegionManager, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping? "

But above code works I put it into some ViewModel and inject IRegionManager in that.

like

```
 public HeaderControlViewModel(IEventAggregator aggregator, IRegionManager regionManager)
        : base(aggregator)
    {
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
        this.regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TextRegion", typeof(TextView));
    }
```

But i dont want to do this. I want everything to be configured with bootstrapper only.

Please tell me why bootstrapper is not able to get RegionManager object? How can i solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: After doing some RND i got the issue. Earlier i was trying to access RegionManager instance in method ConfigureContainer() of bootstrapper. I moved my code to InitializeModules(). Now its working fine.

Comment: Hmmm, I disagree with the closure of this.  I was having exactly the same problem and the self-reply by DJ is exactly what I was looking for.  This is an example of more than one person (me and DJ) hitting an exception and looking for help in solving.  OK, the Prism documents probably explain, but they're hardly gripping reading!

Comment: I agree, this is a valid working with prism question, I fail to see how it's different than all of the other 'working with x framework' questions that are allowed. 

Also, thanks for the self-reply, it also helped me.

Answer (score -1):

//...App.xaml.cs

```
   public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            Bootstrapper bs = new Bootstrapper();
            bs.Run();
            bs.ShowDefault();
        }
    }
```

//... Bootstrapper.cs

```
public void ShowDefault()
{
   RegionManager.GetRegionManager(Application.Current.MainWindow)
.RequestNavigate("MainRegion", "ViewA");
}
```

//...